# Oracle SQL "complex" group by query optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, optimization

I have an Oracle Report (10g) where i created several graphs.

Now i use two statements like the following in this report. I feel like i had to use two sub-selects in order to get all information the way i want it. 
But the report now uses 7min to generate and i'm wondering if there's anyway to optimize this query

```
SELECT quantity ,
  commodity ,
  TO_CHAR(quantity,'9999999990.000') string_quantity
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(quantity) quantity ,
    commodity
  FROM
    (SELECT vtr.quant_p quantity,
      DECODE(vtr.commo_num,'CU','CU,MS,PB','MS','CU,MS,PB','PB','CU,MS,PB',vtr.commo_num) commodity
    FROM v_transactions_postp vtr
    WHERE vtr.compa_num = :P_COMPA_NUM
    AND vtr.customer    = :P_CUSTOMER
    AND vtr.POSTPERIOD BETWEEN :P_PP_START AND :P_PP_END
    )
  GROUP BY commodity
  )
ORDER BY quantity DESC
```

Comment: Can you provide information on indexes created on tables ?

Comment: My question is purely about the query itself. I am fully aware that a lot of performance problems are in the database itself. But in the beginning my report took 1min to generate. now it takes 7. So i'm just trying to see if there is another way to do this query (with less subselects)

Comment: Please attach an explain plan of the query to the question - run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select .... the rest of the query`, then run `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY)`, then copy a result of last query *as a text-not bitmap* and paste in into the question.

Comment: Oracle will most likely rewrite your query to remove the inline views; I doubt they are the cause of your performance problem.

Comment: The query looks fine as is. On first glance, I don't see any option on how to optimize it. You should of course have an appropriate index. How many records do you get with your innermost query? How many rows does the final query produce?

Comment: @Boneist, Oh, ok. Thanks for the info. I guess i will have to do some more investigating then :)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner unfortunately i have no power over indexes and such but i will see with our dba that all indexes are done appropriately. Thank you for your input. The innermost query (with my default test parameters) returns 952 rows

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can records exist where `commo_num = 'CU,MS,PB'`?

Comment: An Aggregation on 1000 rows should be rather quick. So I guess selecting those thousand rows alone takes several minutes. Correct?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner 1. I'm not sure if i understand correctly... There are no records where commo_num = 'CU,MS,PB' but there are records where commo_num IN ('CU','MS','PB') and they are supposed to be displayed in one category.
2. Yes you are correct. Querrying the view alone is very slow but i thought that statement with a subselect, with another subselect was not very elegant and i assumed that this would also make the db do unnecessary work. But as it turns out even with an "optimized" query the performance differences are rather minimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT sum(vtr.quant_p) quantity,
 (CASE WHEN vtr.commo_num IN ('CU','MS','PB') THEN 'CU,MS,PB' ELSE vtr.commo_num) commodity,
 TO_CHAR(sum(vtr.quant_p), '9999999990.000') string_quantity
 FROM v_transactions_postp vtr
   WHERE vtr.compa_num = :P_COMPA_NUM
     AND vtr.customer = :P_CUSTOMER
     AND vtr.POSTPERIOD BETWEEN :P_PP_START AND :P_PP_END
     GROUP BY commodity
     ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

I would suggest you avoid using TO_CHAR in query just to format it in decimal format. You can get quantity and then add formation logic in your code, say in JAVA or PHP.

Comment: I will try that. I had difficulties figuring out custom formatting options in Oracle Reports so i thought it would probably be easier to do it in the query itself.

Comment: That was an suggestion if you can do as I think it will increase performance. Else you can do to_char in query.

Comment: I just tried it. i got rid of the to_char in the query and i managed to apply the wanted format in the Report Builder. It actually saved me 1.5 minutes. so thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure. Welcome. Try with both the options and see which one is better and go ahead with it. Also select my answer as correct one if you think it is best one for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need all the subqueries.  And `CASE` is preferable to `DECODE()`, especially in this case where it simplifies the code:

```
SELECT SUM(vtr.quant_p) as quantity,  
       (CASE WHEN vtr.commo_num IN ('CU', 'MS', 'PB') THEN 'CU,MS,PB'
             ELSE vtr.commo_num
        END) as commodity
       TO_CHAR(SUM(vtr.quant_p),'9999999990.000') as string_quantity
FROM v_transactions_postp vtr
WHERE vtr.compa_num = :P_COMPA_NUM AND
      vtr.customer    = :P_CUSTOMER AND
      vtr.POSTPERIOD BETWEEN :P_PP_START AND :P_PP_END
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN vtr.commo_num IN ('CU', 'MS', 'PB') THEN 'CU,MS,PB'
               ELSE vtr.commo_num
          END)
ORDER BY SUM(vtr.quant_p) DESC
```

Then, for performance, you want an index on `v_transactions_postp(compa_num, customer, postperiod)`.  However, I suspect that the "v_" means "view".  That can make the query harder to optimize.  You would need the appropriate index on the underlying tables -- or to expand the view in the query.

Comment: `v_`: well spotted. That escaped me.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  yes the v_ is for view. As i mentioned in another comment i have no power over the DB itself since i'm not the DBA. but i will check with him if theres anything we can do. As for the query: that looks promising! i didn't know you could have "complex" group by / order by clauses i will try that!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, ok i tried it now and it worked. even though the differences are minimal and i still have to consult with the DBA to get more performance out of it. But it's good to know that i can use group by / order by in that way... so thanks a lot!

Comment: @JanZimmermann if you can get the definition of the view, you may find that some of the logic in the view is unnecessary for your query. If you can remove that extraneous logic, you will most likely be able to speed up your query. Of course, it may not be possible, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: @Boneist Hi, thanks for your comment, but i think i already got the most performance out of my statement i can get :) .. The problem with the view is that i can't change it. Because it is used at several other places in the application.

Comment: @JanZimmermann I wasn't talking about changing the view itself, more like taking the select statement generating the view and removing anything that isn't necessary. E.g. Say your view is `select t1.col1, t2.col2 from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1)` but you were only interested in the t1.col1 values, then you'd simply remove the left outer join from the query, as it's irrelevant for your needs. That's a highly simplified example, of course, but hopefully you get what I mean, now?